# EntityFramework DataBase First. Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "" в файле конфигурации приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Использую подход DataBase First. Entity сформировал мне сам строку подключения, но он бьёт мне ошибку:Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "" в файле конфигурации приложения.

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TeleSalesCRMEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/WhatsApp.csdl|res://*/WhatsApp.ssdl|res://*/WhatsApp.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;
           data source=sa.ru;
           initial catalog=base;
           user id=sa;
           password=123456;
           MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
           App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Вот так подключаю View и ViewModel

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModelApp/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

При запуске приложения ошибка исчезает, но в момент разработки он вечно выскакивает. Строка подключения правильная, все запросы работают. Но почему ошибка выскакивает не понятно.

```
public partial class TeleSalesCRMEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TeleSalesCRMEntities()
            : base("name=TeleSalesCRMEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
```

Вот ошибка в режиме разработки, а при запуске ее нет. То есть проект норм запускается и тд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно проблема в `&quot;`?

Comment: Что написано в классе контекста базы данных?

Comment: @Jagailo Вроде бы всё правильно. А &quot; это кавычка.

Comment: Пробовали без `name=`?

Comment: @Jagailo В правке код ошибки.

Comment: апппппппппппппп

Comment: Если что, у вас в ошибке русским языком написано, что либо конекшен стринг не для database first указан, либо класс родитель не такой. Ваш код протестировать нельзя, так как нет БД для воспроизведения ситуации, соответственно разбираться в нём не хочеться. Вот [официальный гайд по db-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx), сверяйте с вашими действиями и ищите ошибку.

Comment: @Jagailo Эта ошибка когда я убрал name= возникает. И то проект запускается всё равно и процедуры работают. Эта ошибка в режиме дизайнера.

Comment: @Jagailo все по статье. Но ошибка все равно есть.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Если будет время - посмотрю

Comment: апппппппппппппп